# Writing a declaration file: typescript

Tags: typescript, declaration-files, .d.ts

How would I write a declaration file for

```
define(function() {
    'use strict';
    return Object.freeze({
        BTN_LINK: 'btnLink',
        COMBO_BOX: 'comboBox',
        TEXT: 'text'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the object you have frozen is:

```
type example = Readonly<{ BTN_LINK: string; COMBO_BOX: string; TEXT: string; }>;
```

You can get some guidance on [best practices](http://definitelytyped.org/guides/best-practices.html), and detailed instructions on writing [type definitions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) if you want to find out more about ambient types. In particular, the best practices link describes how to create ghost modules, which you will be interested in if you want to put this type into a ghost module to describe the whole file.